# How to stop sending email templates from salesforce to the associated contacts for old cases

Tags: email-template

Recently in our org we started to work on the data clean up as a part of it we backed up all the cases accounts contacts and inserted the data of last 1 year but the business wants to look at all the cases which we backed. Now the main issue when I try to insert this cases in salesforce an auto email templates is sent to the contacts which created the confusion for them. Is there a way where I can inactive sending emails from salesforce for a while and this setting back to active when the upsert is done. We are not using the auto responsible rules. I'm not able to find what else we might be using to send this auto response templates.

Comment: did you check you workflow actions? Which is sending that notifications?

Answer (score 1):

deactivate your Case Auto-Response Rules.